# regex replace repeated (emoticon) characters python

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace `:)` / `:))))`... with `+` for as many occurrences as seen.
e.g.:

```
:)     -> +
:)))   -> +++
```

And same for negative :

```
:(     -> -
:(((   -> ---
```

It should also match for left-handed emoticons:

```
(:     -> +
(((:   -> +++

):     -> -
))):   -> ---
```

Possible ? :)

Comment: Everything is possible.

Comment: @MarounMaroun ^^ with regex :-)

Comment: @AvinashRaj Still, everything is possible ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not?

```
>>> def get_emoticon(txt):
    return re.sub(r':(([\(\)])+)', lambda m:  '-'*len(m.group(1)) if m.group(2) == '(' else  '+' * len(m.group(1)), txt)

>>> get_emoticon(':) hi :))) how r you? :((( :(')
'+ hi +++ how r you? --- -'
>>>
```

Update:

```
>>> def get_emoticon(txt):
    def func(match):
        if match.group().startswith(':'):
            return '-'*len(match.group(1)) if match.group(2) == '(' else  '+' * len(match.group(1))
        return '+'*len(match.group(3)) if match.group(4) == '(' else  '-' * len(match.group(3))
    return re.sub(r':(([\(\)])+)|(([\(\)])+):', lambda m: func(m), txt)

>>> get_emoticon(':) (: hi :))) how r you? :((( :(')
'+ + hi +++ how r you? --- -'
>>> get_emoticon(':) (: ))): hi :))) how r you? :((( :(')
'+ + --- hi +++ how r you? --- -'
>>>
```

Comment: is it possible to get the result as `+ hi +++ how r you ? -` ?  I want to skip the `:`

Comment: oh , forget to remove `:` in the return stmt

Comment: Halfway through... :) But it unfortunately doesn't work for left-handed emoticons... `(:`

Comment: @Kevad could you figure out the remaining part of your own?

Comment: Everything's possible ;)